# Separate value from comma to row SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql

Please help me to get value from table like below

`Field A` has value below

```
file B
13974
14098
14237
14269
....
```

and I need to mix values and down value in row like below

```
13974;14098;14237;14269;14317;14319;14392;14393;13 257;13983;13820
```

please help me to supports many thanks

Comment: Which DB you are using??

Comment: Try to use Group Concat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For SQL-Server you can use,

```
select SUBSTRING(
    (select ';' + your_column
     from your_table
     for xml path('')),2,10000) as csv
```

** 10000 is the end position of the substring. So replace this with the maximum number of characters you expect in your result.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @xxx nvarchar(max)  
select top 10 @xxx =COALESCE(@xxx+';','')+columnName
from table
select @xxx
```